# Why doesn't this overflow?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, int, integer-overflow

Given this code:

```
int x = 20000;
int y = 20000;
int z = 40000;

// Why is it printing WTF? Isn't 40,000 > 32,767?
if ((x + y) == z) Console.WriteLine("WTF?");
```

And knowing an int can hold −32,768 to +32,767. Why doesn't this cause an overflow?

Comment: int in 32-bit machine is 4 bytes, most of the time.

Comment: Did you try printing out "x+y", then printing out z? Maybe they both get stored as the same negative number.

Comment: int in C# is 32 bits *always*.

Comment: wow 8 people all answered basically the same way, below

Comment: Just out of intereset: In which programming language is int not an 4 or 8 byte data type?

Comment: I wish all the people who posted later than the original correct answer would delete their redundant answers...

Comment: @Oliver - some C/C++ implementations will have a 16-bit int.  Admittedly, no modern desktops platforms will, but older ones (think MS-DOS) or some embedded platforms will.  Not that any of this has to do with C#.

Comment: @Oliver, One example is C, the C standard does NOT define the size of the 'int' type. The standard states "a 'plain' int object has the natural size suggested by the architecture of the execution environment (large enough to contain any value in the range INT_MIN to INT_MAX...". Which basically means int can be anything as long as it's at least 16bits (INT_MIN is 2^15 and INT_MAX is 2^15-1)

Comment: Yeah, I thought of C (therefore I also wrote 4 or 8 bytes because I think on 64-bit systems C has an 8 byte integer), but taking the environment into account on which he runs his C# application, I do not think that it will be a 16-Bit hardware ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In C#, the [`int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx) type is mapped to the [`Int32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx) type, which is always 32-bits, signed.

Even if you use [`short`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4.aspx), it still won't overflow because `short` + `short` returns an [`int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx) by default. If you cast this `int` to `short` - `(short)(x + y)` - you'll get an overflowed value. You won't get an exception though. You can use [`checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) behavior to get an exception:

```
using System;

namespace TestOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            short x = 20000;
            short y = 20000;
            short z;

            Console.WriteLine("Overflowing with default behavior...");
            z = (short)(x + y);
            Console.WriteLine("Okay! Value is {0}. Press any key to overflow " +
                "with 'checked' keyword.", z);
            Console.ReadKey(true);

            z = checked((short)(x + y));
        }
    }
}
```

You can find information about [`checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) (and [`unchecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx)) on MSDN. It basically boils down to performance, because checking for overflow is a little bit slower than ignoring it (and that's why the default behavior is usually `unchecked`, but I bet that in some compilers/configurations you'll get an exception on the first `z` assignment.)

Comment: +1 I'd just add Scoregraphic's link here to make it a complete and great answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I added some links to Int32, int and short types =)

Answer (score 10):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx

Type: int
Range: -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

Comment: Downvoted because the answer isn't complete. See the answer that describes checked arithmetic.

Comment: The answer is complete in regard of the original question (why is there no overflow). So in my opinion, a downvote is wrong. But do an upvote on your prefered solution instead.

Answer (score 6):

While everyone is correct in saying that an "int" type on a 32 bit machine is most likely 2^32, there is a glaring flaw in your methodology.

Let's assume that int was 16 bit. You're assigning a value that will overflow z, so z itself is overflowed. When you calculate x+y you're also overflowing the int type, it's very likely that both cases will overflow to the same value, meaning you'd hit your equality regardless(this is probably compiler dependent, I'm not quite sure whether x+y will be promoted).

The correct way to do your experiment would be for z to have a larger data type than x and y. For example(Sorry for plain C, I'm not much of C# person. Hopefully it illustrated the methodology, however.)

```
int x = INT_MAX;
int y = INT_MAX;
int sum = x + y;
long long z = INT_MAX+INT_MAX;
if(sum == z) 
 printf("Why didn't sum overflow?!\n");
```

Comparing sum and z is important as comparing x+y and z may still come out fine depending on how the compiler handles promotion.

Comment: Great C example. I actually got this off of a C guy's blog, but asked it in C# because were on SO and it gave the same result.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, an Int is 4 bytes.  So it maxes out at 2^31 or 2,147,483,648.  If you want a 2 byte integer, use a short instead of an int.

Answer (score 2):

Because an int in .NET is a **signed 32 bit** number with a range of **-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647**.

Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Because ints are 32-bit, holding values up to ±2GB.

Answer (score 1):

An int's size is 4 byte so it can hold at least 2^31 which is around 2 billion.

Answer (score 1):

The [int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w%28VS.80%29.aspx) keyword maps to the .NET Framework [Int32 type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32%28VS.100%29.aspx), which can hold integers in the range from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

Answer (score 1):

in C# **int (System.Int32)** is of 32 bits which can happily store this value.

Answer (score 1):

you are given to print the result as "WTF?" .Then how should it display other value.

Int means int32 its range is –2147483648 to 2147483647
you are given the range of int16 :–32768 to 32767

This is the reason it is not throwing any error

Answer (score 1):

First of all your code is in the range for int... However if it were not in the range then it wont complain either... coz you are never assigning a value back to any variable after doing X+Y in your if check...

Suppose if you were doing X * Y then it'll be calculated and the result would be a long value then the value from variable Z is taken and promoted to a long then both would be compared... Remember the casting from a lower range primitive to upper range primitive value is implicit.

```
int x = 200000; //In your code it was 20000
int y = 200000; //In your code it was 20000
int z = 40000;

// Why is it printing WTF? Isn't 40,000 > 32,767?
// Note: X + Y = 200000 and not < 32,767 
// would pass compiler coz you are not assigning and values are compared as longs
// And since it's not equals to 40,000 the WTF did not got printed
if ((x + y) == z) Console.WriteLine("WTF?");     
// And x * y >= z is true WTF MULTIPLY got printed
if ((x * y) >= z) Console.WriteLine("WTF MULTIPLY?"); 
// Compiler would fail since x can't hold 40,00,00,00,000
x = x * y;
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above is true, however, it's important to know, that if you assign a number greater than 2^32, it will not compile!